# Why this java snippet code compile just fine?

Tags: java, generics

1.1 example

```
import java.util.*;

public class LOLUnknowns1 {
    static void probablyIllegal(List<List<?>> lol, List<?> list) {
        lol.add(list); // this compiles just fine
    }
}
```

How come this 1.1 code compile if we may end up having List<List<Integer>> lol and a List<String> list?

this following code snippet:
1.2 example

```
import java.util.*;

public class TwoListsOfUnknowns2 {
    static void doSomethingIllegal(List<?> list1, List<?> list2) {
        list1.addAll(list2); // DOES NOT COMPILE as expected!!!
            
    }
}
```

1.1 example baffles me, how is that possible to be compiled just fine?

I wnat to know the specific reason why a code compiled when it was expected not to from my understanding

Comment: Are you getting an unchecked cast exception? In the second case, you cannot add to a List<?> because you don't know what ? is. In the first case, you know you have a List. A List<?> is still just a List after type erasure.

Comment: @Matt [No unchecked cast exception.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76452723/1744774)

Answer (score 2):

> How come this 1.1 code compile if we may end up having `List<List<Integer>> lol` and a `List<String> list`?

You can **not** pass a `List<List<Integer>>` to an argument of type `List<List<?>>`. If you try:

```
probablyIllegal(new ArrayList<List<Integer>>(), new ArrayList<String>());
```

you get

> The method `probablyIllegal(List<List<?>>, List<?>)` in the type `LOLUnknowns1` is not applicable for the arguments `(ArrayList<List<Integer>>, ArrayList<String>`).

The reason is that even though a `List<Integer>` is a subtype of `List<?>`, `List<List<Integer>>` is not a subtype of `List<List<?>>`, just like, even though `String` is a subtype of `Object`, `List<String>` is not a subtype of `List<Object>`.

If you want to be able to pass a `List<List<Integer>>`, you need to declare the argument to be of type `List<? extends List<?>>`:

```
static void probablyIllegal(List<? extends List<?>> lol, List<?> list) {
    lol.add(list); 
}
```

After that change, the compiler will accept your call, but reject your method implementation:

> The method `add(capture#1-of ? extends List<?>)` in the type `List<capture#1-of ? extends List<?>>` is not applicable for the arguments `(List<capture#2-of ?>)`

The error message is a bit cryptic (you need to read up on wildcard capture to understand it), but it basically says that you can't add the `List<?>` to a `List<? extends List<?>>` because you don't know what kind of elements `lol` contains, and therefore can not know that `list` is of a compatible type.

To conclude, you can either specify a specific element type for the `List`, in which case you can `add`, but not use a `List` of a different type, or you can leave the element type of the `List` unspecified, in which case you can use any `List`, but not `add` anything to it. Either way, nothing bad happens.

Answer (score 0):

##### Re 1.1

As long as you don't use `extends` or `super` in a [generic declaration with wildcards](https://www.baeldung.com/java-generics#bd-wildcards) the compiler can't decide whether this will work or not at runtime since with the sole `?` you tell it: *I want to accept anything*, and so does [`add(E e)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#add(E)).

Have you tried running the code with concrete `List` objects passed as `lol`, `list`, `list1`, `list2` arguments?

#### Re 1.2

The error (in Eclipse here) is:

> The method addAll(Collection<? extends capture#1-of ?>) in the type List<capture#1-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments (List<capture#2-of ?>)

So, there are two different [*wildcard captures*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/capture.html). One of `Collection<?>` (#1; expected by [`addAll(Collection<? extends E> c)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#addAll(java.util.Collection)))/`List<?> list1` and one of `List<?> list2` (#2).

Now, see the article under the first link above:

> However, a collection of *Object* is not the supertype of any collection.
>
> For example, a *List<Object>* is not the supertype of *List<String>*, [...]

You declare `list1` to be a `List` of anything (`?`<sub>1</sub>) hence `addAll()` expects something (`?`<sub>2</sub>) that extends anything (`E` = `?`<sub>1</sub>) but, see the citation, that's not how generics work.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is [what](https://www.baeldung.com/java-generics#:%7E:text=Wildcards%20are%20represented%20by%20the,used%20as%20a%20parameter%20type.) are you looking for.

To summarise a bit, for the second example you have can be done by a upper-bounded wildcard, if you want to have a list of more types.

In your first example you have an extra wrapper, the `List<?>` this is why it works, in the end a method from the List interface is used.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).